# Lightning Web Component error while logging

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

I am new to the Lightning Web Component , When i am running the command to login to the dev org from my VS Code terminal window then i am getting the below error :

Command : `C:\Users\ABHIJEET KUMAR\LWC Session>sfdx force:auth:web:login -a lwc101 -d`

Error:

```
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=c03a597411b9^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=PbNmfd03hcmRtSpg8hcCrPhA8BQF7BQCdsxKYHVC5kM' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=c03a597411b9^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=PbNmfd03hcmRtSpg8hcCrPhA8BQF7BQCdsxKYHVC5kM' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=c03a597411b9^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=PbNmfd03hcmRtSpg8hcCrPhA8BQF7BQCdsxKYHVC5kM' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=c03a597411b9^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=PbNmfd03hcmRtSpg8hcCrPhA8BQF7BQCdsxKYHVC5kM' ] }
```

Comment: I solved it by myself : Just need to kill the busy port and res start the VS code again it will work.

Comment: you can add this as answer by yourself.

Comment: @Abhijeet Kumar Also there is no need to write commands to perform such activities. Install Salesforce Extension Pack & then use Ctrl + Shift + P